# Intellij Not finding installed CLI commands - Especially MongoDump/Restore

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea

when i try to run a file with IntelliJ it does not recognize the Mongo CLI commands like mongodump

but what is weird is that when trying to run the same command on my local machine in the terminal it's there, the same goes when trying to do it manually on the terminal tab in IntelliJ ,

i am using zsh

```
/bin/sh: mongodump: command not found
at ChildProcess.exithandler (node: child process: 397:12)
at ChildProcess.emit (node: events: 390:28)
at ChildProcess.emit (node: domain:475:12)
at maybeClose (node: internal/child process: 1064:16)
at Socket. <anonymous> (node: internal/child process: 450:11)
at Socket.emit (node: events:390:28)
at Socket.emit (node: domain: 475:12)
at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:687:12)
at Pipe.callbackTrampoline (node: internal/async hooks:130:17)
```

this is the message i get when running the file through IntelliJ

Comment: what OS is it? does it work if you start IDEA [from terminal](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011901879-How-to-start-IDE-from-the-command-line#h_9eb22313-2b74-4d6c-996e-6fb08dacc95f)?

Comment: MacOS , tried `open -a Intellij` the same happens was thinking that it will give it the same context of the shell , no success